# Create array of objects based on object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a some json data that I want to transform into an array of objects that should have the following structure:

```
var names =[{
   name:"2Anita",
   years:[1916,1917],
   born:[11,20]
},
{
   name:"2Anna",
   years:[1916,1917],
   born:[153,91]
}]
```

The source data has this structure:

```
{
    "people": [{
        "key": ["2Anita", "1916"],
        "values": ["11"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anita", "1917"],
        "values": ["20"]
    },  {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1916"],
        "values": ["153"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1917"],
        "values": ["91"]
    }]
}
```

This is what I have achieved so far:

```
var people = [{
        "key": ["2Anita", "1916"],
        "values": ["11"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anita", "1917"],
        "values": ["20"]
    },  {
        "key": ["2Ann", "1920"],
        "values": [".."]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1916"],
        "values": ["153"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1917"],
        "values": ["91"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Ann-Christin", "1916"],
        "values": [".."]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Ann-Christin", "1917"],
        "values": [".."]
    }]

var tempNames = [];
var names = [];

    //Creating array that holds every unique name
    people.forEach(function functionName(v, k) {
        if (tempNames.indexOf(v.key[0]) === -1) {
            tempNames.push(v.key[0])
        }
    });

    //Creating array with objects for each unique name
    tempNames.forEach(function(v, k) {
        names.push({
            name: v,
            years: [],
            born: []
        })
    });
```

JS Bin:

https://jsbin.com/qofuqatoqo/1/edit?html,js,console

**EDIT:**

My final solution:

```
  var grouped = _.groupBy(people, function(num) {
        return num.key[0];
    });

    var j = 0;
    var n = _.each(grouped, function(val) {
        vm.names.push({
            name: val[0].key[0],
            years: [],
            born: []
        })
        for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            vm.names[j].years.push(val[i].key[1]);
            vm.names[j].born.push(val[i].values[0]);
            vm.years.push(val[i].key[1]);
        }
        j++;
    });
```

Comment: Your final solution is good, for all others: _ is object of underscore.js library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, uses object as dictionary to store are keys,
then transform that dictionary to desired array.

```js
var input={
    "people": [{
        "key": ["2Anita", "1916"],
        "values": ["11"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anita", "1917"],
        "values": ["20"]
    },  {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1916"],
        "values": ["153"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1917"],
        "values": ["91"]
    }]
}

var inputArray = input.people;

var dictionary = {}
inputArray.forEach(function(v){
  if(dictionary[v.key[0]]==null)
  {
    dictionary[v.key[0]] = {
      years:[parseInt(v.key[1])],
      born:[ parseInt(v.values[0])]
    }
  } else {
    dictionary[v.key[0]].years.push(parseInt(v.key[1]));
    dictionary[v.key[0]].born.push(parseInt(v.values[0]));
  }
});

var final = [];

for (var key in dictionary)
{
  final.push({
   name: key,
   years:dictionary[key].years,
   born:dictionary[key].born
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach

```
let data = {
    "people": [{
        "key": ["2Anita", "1916"],
        "values": ["11"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anita", "1917"],
        "values": ["20"]
    },  {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1916"],
        "values": ["153"]
    }, {
        "key": ["2Anna", "1917"],
        "values": ["91"]
    }]
}

let auxNames = data.people.reduce((initial, item) => {

  if (!initial.hasOwnProperty(item.key[0])) {
          initial[item.key[0]] = {
      years: [],
      born: []
    }  
  }

  initial[item.key[0]].years.push(item.key[1])
  initial[item.key[0]].born.push(item.values[0])

    return initial
}, {})

const names = []

for (let prop in auxNames) {
    names.push({
    name: prop,
    years: auxNames[prop].years,
    born: auxNames[prop].born
  })
}
```